# Connecting to printer hub from Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, mac, printer, osx-lion, print-server

I have a print server that I had been using to connect my Windows machines with my Canon printer via my LAN connection. Recently I switched to Mac, and I disovered that this server is not working on the Mac. The error message I get is:

> The version of the server you are trying to connect to is not
>   supported. Please contact your system administrator to resolve the
>   problem.

My print server is [IOGear PS Print Server](http://www.iogear.com/support/dm/driver/GPSU01#display). As you can see, the maker does not offer a driver for Mac. Does this mean I should not expect to make this server work with Mac and just give up? What are my options if I want to fix this thing? If I cannot, what should I use instead?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Apple disabled older versions of AFP / AppleTalk in Lion due to security concerns. After looking at the manual for your print server - it does support OS X, but you're not seeing drivers on the website because they are readily available in the OS. The manual refers to AppleTalk in the protocols available on the device.

[IOGear GPSU01 PDF Manual](http://www.iogear.com/support/manual/714%20GPSU01%20manual_v2.pdf)

It appears that there is a work-around for enabling Lion to talk with the older (less-secure) devices. The following link is to a guide that will show you how to do so. Instead of step 2, attempt to add the printer in System Preferences- it may fail and then go to step 3. Once you're done with the guide, try to install again and see what happens.

[Enable older AFP connections](http://www.alexanderwilde.com/2011/04/os-x-lion-connection-error-with-afp-and-workaround/)

Good Luck!